# Cannot connect to s3 static web page using URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have set up a bucket on Amazon S3 called www.mirrorssmoke.com.

This URL connects to it:
http://www.mirrorssmoke.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
There is only some basic text there now so that I can see that I connected to it.

I set up route53 (but maybe that is where the problem is) to route to this page.

dig reports this:

```
dig ANY www.mirrorssmoke.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ANY www.mirrorssmoke.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20438
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.mirrorssmoke.com.      IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-785.awsdns-34.net.
www.mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-86.awsdns-10.com.
www.mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1043.awsdns-02.org.
www.mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1837.awsdns-37.co.uk.
www.mirrorssmoke.com.   900 IN  SOA ns-86.awsdns-10.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 57 msec
;; SERVER: 209.18.47.61#53(209.18.47.61)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 12 10:52:32 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 235
```

browsing to www.mirrorssmoke.com returns this:

www.mirrorssmoke.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

I registered the domain on go daddy and tried (apparently unsuccessfully) to route the www.mirrorssmoke.com to the s3 bucket.  I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what that is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the above that the host `www` is configured with an `SOA` record, and also with `NS` records.  This not a correct DNS configuration.

Only the root domain itself (mirrorssmoke.com) should reference the `SOA/NS` records.

In order to advertise the `www` host, the `www` record should be a `CNAME` to www.mirrorssmoke.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

The correct record set would look like this:

```
mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-785.awsdns-34.net.
mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-86.awsdns-10.com. 
mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1043.awsdns-02.org. 
mirrorssmoke.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns-1837.awsdns-37.co.uk. 
mirrorssmoke.com.   900 IN  SOA ns-86.awsdns-10.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
www 3600 IN CNAME www.mirrorssmoke.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Basically the `www` record is not returning an IP number, and has no valid DNS - which is what the browser is reporting.  A normal host record would use a `A` or a `CNAME` record. In this case a `CNAME` alias the the s3 website address is required.

I am guessing that when you created the zone in Route 53, you gave it www.mirrorssmoke.com as the domain name. If so, you should delete that zone, and create a new zone for mirrorssmoke.com. Then you can add the `www` record correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.